# Issue playing Video Games on PC with Bluetooth Earbuds

Tags: audio, bluetooth, troubleshooting, gaming

So today I've been trying to troubleshoot my wireless bluetooth earbuds all day and just can't seem to find a solution to exactly what I'm experiencing. For example, when I first pair them everything works when I'm just using Chrome. Youtube doesn't seem to have a delay and quality is perfect. So I launch a video game (Escape from Tarkov) and all of my sound immediately disables. No more audio when I go to youtube and no in game audio. Found a solution showing that my new device is actually two new devices and to disable the second one for input and output and just use the Headphones device for output, not headset. So I do this and the audio works but now there is at least a 1 second delay in game only. So I try disabling the headphones and only enabling the headset for input and output. There is no more sound delay in game, however the audio quality sounds like it's playing an 8-bit game from back in the day.

So I have two choices great sound but having at least a 1 second delay, or having terrible sound without delay. Is there any advice to my problem here or are these my only options? I'm using Bose Quiet Comfort Plus earbuds if that helps.

Comment: *"the audio quality sounds like it's playing an 8-bit game from back in the day"* That's exactly what should be expected and it has always been like that.

Comment: This is how Bluetooth has worked for the last 20 years and is unlikely to change. Chrome is fine because it is just playing video and can adjust the delay on the video so that audio and video are in sync. Games don't have that option because they play noises as a response to your actions. Get a non-bluetooth wireless headset. Bluetooth is only good for music and films. There are supposedly "low latency" codecs with good audio, but their support across headphones and computers is patchy at best.